# ColdFusion doesn't serialize all properties to JSON

Tags: coldfusion, cfc, coldfusion-11

When I serialize a component to JSON it only outputs the properties which are set or which have a default value. In my example you can see that the property `phone` is not getting serialized. Is there any way to change that behaviour in ColdFusion?

User.cfc:

```
component accessors="true" {
    property name="firstName";
    property name="lastName";
    property name="email" default="";
    property name="phone";
}
```

Create new user, set properties and serialize to JSON:

```
var user = new User();
user.setFirstName("Homer");
user.setLastName("Simpson");
writeOutput(serializeJSON(user));
```

The JSON output:

```
{"firstName":"Homer","email":"","lastName":"Simpson"}
```

Comment: Wouldn't having default values for all the properties help?

Comment: Probably adding default value will help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say what you're seeing is a bug in ColdFusion 11, so you should raise it accordingly on the [bug tracker](https://bugbase.adobe.com/).

Fortunately ColdFusion 11 has a (fairly poorly realised, IMO) mechanism for you to define your own serialisation process for components.

The docs for this functionality is at "[Support for pluggable serializer and deserializer](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/RESTful+Web+Services+in+ColdFusion#RESTfulWebServicesinColdFusion-Supportforpluggableserializeranddeserializer)", and I go through some investigation on my blog here: "[ColdFusion 11: custom serialisers. More questions than answers](http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2014/04/coldfusion-11-custom-serialisers-more.html)".

How to implement this is too long-winded for a Stack Overflow answer, and it's all well documented in the official docs.

Comment: Not sure I agree that this is a 'bug'. How would you represent a `null` value in JSON? If a property on a CFC has not been set, and there is no default, it is, for all intents and purposes, `null`. The equivalent to `null` in JavaScript would be, in my opinion, `undefined`. By not including the property in the JSON string it is `undefined` in JavaScript.

Comment: @ScottStroz read the JSON spec. It has a `null` keyword. And CF quite happily uses it in other situations (repro: `<cfoutput>#serializeJson({key="value",nullKey=javaCast("null", "")})#</cfoutput>` results in `{"NULLKEY":null,"KEY":"value"}`).

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone else is dealing with this on CF9, the way I solved the issue was by using Jackson (download core, annotations, and databind) from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core), then using JavaLoader to mount the JARs:

```
    <Cfset var paths = []>
    <cfset paths[1] = expandPath("/api/v1/lib/jackson-core-2.0.0.jar")>
    <cfset paths[2] = expandPath("/api/v1/lib/jackson-annotations-2.0.0.jar")>
    <cfset paths[3] = expandPath("/api/v1/lib/jackson-databind-2.0.0.jar")>
    <cfset application.javaloader = createObject("component", "javaloader.JavaLoader").init(paths)>
```

Then calling Jackson from my CFC:

```
    <cfset variables.jackson = application.jackson />
    <cfset var json = jackson.writeValueAsString(variables.data) />
```

Just note that you'll need to JavaCast the variables from ColdFusion in order to get the correct boolean, numeric, and integer values (no auto-typing like the built in serializer.)  Jackson is much faster and (despite the explicit typing required) more reliable than a custom serializer.